# What does $d\zeta_1\wedge\cdots\wedge d\zeta_n$ mean in the context of Cauchy formula (on polydiscs)?

Tags: complex-analysis, multivariable-calculus, notation, differential-forms

A Polydisc of center $z^o=(z_1^o,\dots,z_n^o)\in\Bbb C^n$ and multiradius $r=(r_1,\dots,r_n)\in(\Bbb R^+)^n$ is defined as
$$
P_{z^o,r}:=\prod_{j=1}^n\Delta_{z_j^o,r_j}
$$
where $\Delta_{z_j^o,r_j}:=\{z_j\in\Bbb C\;:\;|z_j-z_j^o|<r_j\}$, for $j=1,\dots,n$.

Then we define
$$
\partial_0 P:=\{z=(z_1,\dots,z_n)\in\Bbb C^n\;:\;|z_j-z_j^o|=r_j\;,\; j=1,\dots,n\}
$$

Let now $f:\Bbb C^n\to\Bbb C$ be continous on $\bar P$, where $P$ is a polydisc; suppose $f$ then holomorphic on every $z_j$, when the other $n-1$ variables are fixed.
Then in my book I read that Cauchy formula becomes
$$
f(z)=(2\pi i)^{-n}\int_{\partial_0 P}\frac{f(\zeta)}{(\zeta_1-z_1)\cdots(\zeta_n-z_n)}\,d\zeta_1\wedge\cdots\wedge d\zeta_n
$$
for every $z\in P$.

What $d\zeta_1\wedge\cdots\wedge d\zeta_n$ mean? Is the usual $d\zeta_1\cdots d\zeta_n$, or does it deal with differential forms/external products and similar stuff?

I would like to know what are the tools to study that will allow me to understand and work with the kind of integrals as above.

Can someone give me some examples of computation of such an integral? I really don't know where to start.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: It is the wedge product of forms. You can view $\partial_{0}P$ as a complex manifold. The $n$ fold wedge will give a measure a measure on this manifold which you can integrate against.

Comment: Also, I don't think you want the wedge in the denominator.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Where can I find some notes about this?

Comment: I'm not a great person to ask for a reference, as complex geometry is a bit outside my field of expertise. However, a brief account can be found in a book by M. Nakahara called "Geometry, Topology and physics. I think it's in Chapter 7, or somewhere around there.

Comment: @user43687: $\partial_0P$ is far from a complex manifold. It's a real $n$-torus. (Consider the case $n=1$.)

Comment: @TedShifrin: ok. So how must I interpretate the integral? I'm furiously looking at my analysis books, and the nearest things I saw are the $2$-forms. I would like to know what are the tools to study that will allow me to understand and work with the kind of integrals as above.

Comment: The general philosophy is that you can tensor everything in sight with $\mathbf{C}$ and then extend maps like the exterior derivative to be $\mathbf{C}$-linear.

Comment: @Hoot: thank you! But can you be more precise, please? Thanks again

Comment: @TedShifrin: You are absolutely right. I, admittedly, did not read the problem carefully and assumed (a dangerous practice for mathematicians) that the resulting manifold would be complex.

Answer (score 1):

Since $\partial_0P$ is a product of $n$ circles, you can just think of this, indeed, as an $n$-fold iterated integral such as you do with the usual one-dimensional Cauchy Integral Formula. That is, parametrizing each of the circles in the usual way as $\zeta_j = z_j+r_je^{i\theta_j}$, $j=1,\dots,n$, you can rewrite the integral as the iterated integral
$$\frac1{(2\pi i)^n}\int_0^{2\pi}\dots\int_0^{2\pi} f\big(z_1+r_1e^{i\theta_1},\dots,z_n+r_ne^{i\theta_n}\big) d\theta_1\dots d\theta_n.$$

(That being said, if you're going to study several complex variables or complex geometry seriously, you absolutely need to learn differential forms.)